# Ada SPARK read binary file

Tags: ada

I have this code in utils-file.ads,

```
package Utils.File with
   SPARK_Mode
is
    procedure Read_Content (File_Name : String);
end Utils.File;
```

and the corresponding utils-file.adb

```
with Interfaces;
with Ada.Sequential_IO;

package body Utils.File with
   SPARK_Mode => Off
is
    package Seq is new Ada.Sequential_IO (Interfaces.Unsigned_8);

    procedure Read_Content (File_Name : String) with
       SPARK_Mode => Off
    is
        Handle : Seq.File_Type;
        Item   : Interfaces.Unsigned_8 := 0;
    begin
        Seq.Open (Handle, Seq.In_File, File_Name);
        Seq.Read (Handle, Item);
        Seq.Close (Handle);
    end Read_Content;
end Utils.File;
```

I try to call it from my main program,

```
with Utils.File;

procedure Main with
   SPARK_Mode => On
is
begin
    Utils.File.Read_Content ("foo.bin");
end Main;
```

When I run gnatprove, I get this error

```
main.adb:7:15: medium: "memory accessed through objects of access type" might not be initialized after elaboration of main program "Main"
```

It doesn't give that error if I use Text_IO instead of Sequential_IO, but I want to read it as binary and not text. What is it complaining about and how do I fix it?

Comment: Sequential_IO has an unusual semantic. `Handle` in `Seq.Open (Handle, Seq.In_File, File_Name);` is an in out argument. That means `Handle` is not initialised. Your code is correct. You cannot initialise `Handle`, because it is private. But perhaps GNATProve is not aware of this exotic semantic of Sequential_IO or it is confused about it. I would annotate away this message.